# I can't target the Google Login for integration testing

Tags: flutter, dart, integration-testing, google-signin, flutter-integration-test

Currently I'm trying to build out the integration testing for an app that someone else built.  I'm stuck with the Google sign in.

Specifically, the integration testing can't find the Google pop-up page.

Is there any way to use integration testing for the Google sign?

If not, how do I use integration to start on any page I choose for testing?

Please note that I have not built the app; I'm here to test the app.

I've tried to find a page or anything in the files and folders for the pop-up but I can't find anything.

I've even tried using Dart DevTools but I still can't target the sign-in page.

At the very least, can I bypass this step and start the integration on a different page?

Below is a picture of the sign-in page I'm trying to get the Flutter Integration test to interact with.  Note that it has been modified for privacy reasons.

[image]